# Image insertion is working on local server but not on live server

Tags: php, image

Image insertion is not working on live server but when I am running the same code on local server than its working fine. Please tell me how to do that. It's not even inserting the file name in the database. Is there path problem or anything else?

This is my controller:

```
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/upload/'; /* NB! create this dir! */
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
  $config['max_size']  = '2048';
  $config['max_width']  = '5000';
  $config['max_height']  = '5000';
  /* Load the upload library */
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  /* Create the config for image library */
  /* (pretty self-explanatory) */
  $configThumb = array();
  $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
  $configThumb['source_image'] = '';
  $configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
  $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
  /* Set the height and width or thumbs */
  /* Do not worry - CI is pretty smart in resizing */
  /* It will create the largest thumb that can fit in those dimensions */
  /* Thumbs will be saved in same upload dir but with a _thumb suffix */
  /* e.g. 'image.jpg' thumb would be called 'image_thumb.jpg' */
  $configThumb['width'] = 140;
  $configThumb['height'] = 210;
  /* Load the image library */
  $this->load->library('image_lib');
  $file=array();
  $file_thumb=array();
             /* We have 5 files to upload
   * If you want more - change the 6 below as needed
   */
  for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
    /* Handle the file upload */
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'.$i);
    /* File failed to upload - continue */
    if($upload === FALSE) continue;
    /* Get the data about the file */
    $data = $this->upload->data();
  $file[$i] = $data['file_name'];
  $file_thumb[$i] = $data['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$data['file_ext'];


    $uploadedFiles[$i] = $data;
    /* If the file is an image - create a thumbnail */
    if($data['is_image'] == 1) {
      $configThumb['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
      $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
      $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
  }
```

Upload ends here.

Comment: print out $data['full_path'] just to make sure you have a right path

Answer (score 1):

Upload path on live server may not be writable.